How to copy entire selected items in webpage in order to extract URL from search results in website www.archive.org
I hope that I am posting in the right place.
I'm assigned a task to get as many items as possible from the free public website Archive.org regarding ALGEBRA.
So I visited the website chose advanced search filled in the term ALGEBRA in any field location, and set the type to TEXT.
Now the search results are about 47k results.
I tried to load as many pages as possible by using the page-down button.
When I explored the URL of the result I could break it down to see the page number where I am looking right now.
I mean this is the URL:
https://archive.org/search?query=%28algebra%29+AND+mediatype%3A%28texts%29&page=5&and%5B%5D=language%3A%22English%22
It contains the part where it says: page=5
This means that I am now exploring page #5 from the results ....and so on.
The same for the other parts like media type text, and language English.
I tried to select everything on the page copy it and then paste it into Excel or Word and found it only copied the last items shown on my screen but not the entire selected items.
So my question is how to copy the entire selected items on the page so I can complete the copy and paste and then extract the URL of the item.
I found a tool that can extract the URL in Excel and I can use it.
But first I want to be able to do the copy for the entire selected part.
I hope that I was able to express my point correctly.
I googled and found many suggested to open the page elements and add a code to consle but it was not working.

There are tools such as DownThemAll, https://www.downthemall.net, but software recommendation is off-topic here.

Thanks a lot for your reply.
I do not want to download anything but just want to get the URL or the link of the items.
I do not know why when I select many items (for example when I highlight and select the items from the top of the page to the far bottom, which are about 300 or 400 items when I press Ctrl+C or right-click and choose Copy I find only the last 20 items only being copied.
I am searching for any way to copy the entire selection.
